# If I live in my home country, should I apply for a UK visa with my home country passport or can I apply with my other country passport?

Tags: dual-nationality

I have dual nationality and I live in my home country. Can I apply for a UK visa with my other passport or should I apply with my home country passport?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide more information. What passports do you have? What country? Answers may differ depending on your status.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for a UK visa using either passport you like, assuming there are no restrictions on you possessing multiple citizenships.  (From the UK's perspective, it doesn't even matter if you have multiple ones, but if the country where you live found out, and doesn't allow it, it could cause you trouble.)

Typically a passenger would use the passport that affords them the most convenience, so for example, if I were a citizen of Canada and Jamaica, and Jamaican citizens need a visa to visit the UK, it would make more sense to use my Canadian passport, where a visa is not required.

If both nationalities require a visa, choose the one that fits your circumstances best.  Visas vary in price depending on country of citizenship, so you might choose on cost.  Or you might choose on duration; some countries get longer visas than others.  The citizenships you hold will dictate which makes sense.

Ultimately, both passports may be equally suitable and one may have no advantage over the other - you can then choose arbitrarily.  (In this case it might be simpler to use the passport of the country where you are living, since you need to use it to re-enter your home country when you return.*)

*Pedantically speaking you may not *need* it to enter but you are far best to use it when returning home.